# Checking current date with a given date

Tags: javascript, html

I need to check the current date with the date we enter in the input element.

Html code:

```
<input type="date" name="date" id="date>
```

I can get the today's date by the following code in javascript:

```
function todayDate() {
   var today = new Date();
   var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
   var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); 
   var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
   let date=dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
   return date;
 }
```

Now how to check the input date with the current date?

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: What do you mean by "check the input date with the current date"? Do you want to know whether it is before, after or the same as the current date?

Comment: FOLLOW THIS `https://codepen.io/sibabrat_swain/pen/MWKwaVj`

Comment: @loksan please do upvote the comment

Answer (score 1):

I try this using Date Object. 
maybe it will help you. 
first, I set both in Date object and then set time to 00:00:00:00 | hh:mm:ss:ms.  then check using Date getTime function to both are same or not.

```js
function checkDate(e){
var value = e.target.value
var today = new Date()
today.setHours(0,0,0,0) //Reset current Date Time
console.log(value)
var inputDate= new Date(value)
inputDate.setHours(0,0,0,0) // Reset selected Date Time
  if(inputDate.getTime() == today.getTime()){
    console.log('Current Date Selected')
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="date" id="date" onChange="checkDate(event)">
```